# Pixel 2 repeatedly playing a sound alert without explanation, what does it mean? (Sound included)

Tags: audio, alerts

My Pixel 2 has gone crazy in the last few days. Maybe related to the latest Android update that I got a few days ago, but I'm not sure.

I recognize the sound (I have heard it earlier) but it has never behaved like this before. When the screen is on, except in phone calls, it will (randomly?) play this sound over and over, sometimes 20 times in a minute, sometimes it will be quiet for a while. I haven't figured out any logic of when it plays or not, but it stops if the screen is turned off, and it stops during phone calls.

It also plays when using other apps, not just when showing the desktop.

I'm attaching a sound sample here, 28 second recording on the phone itself just lying still.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tQUkt1pUj9yFRGNs6jDoFxsVj7HYnpP8

Comment: is this happens during charging?

Comment: It happens when not charging. I'll put the charger on and see if it also happens then.

Comment: Sounds like a notification from system ? try installing this app and trace the source if possible https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree&hl=en_US

Comment: It also happens while charging.

Comment: Follow up: The phone has stopped doing this, but I don't know why.